# Pipe sc query output to powershell method?

Tags: powershell

I'd like to pipe output from sc query to a method in powershell. For example, checking the status of a service and finding the part that says "STOPPED", and performing an action based on that output.

Is there a way to do this right from the output of sc query? Or do I need to output the results to a text file, and then.. I'm not sure, run a for-loop to find the piece I'm looking for to make an if condition true / false.

This is what I have so far:

```
Function IsStopped {
    sc.exe query remoteregistry >> RemoteRegistry.txt
    Get-Content -Path C:\RemoteRegistry.txt | Where-Object {$_ -like '*stopped*'} | ForEach-Object {


}
```

Not sure where to go next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell has a cmdlet for examining services. Running `Get-Service` without parameters gives you all of the running services in the same way `sc.exe` does (actually while researching this I reminded myself that in PowerShell `sc`, without `.exe`, is an alias for `Set-Content`, so I ended up generating some useless files. This might be another good reason to use `Get-Service` to avoid confusion with `Set-Content`).

Running `Get-Service | Get-Member` gives a list of the properties and methods from the output of the command. `Status` is the Property of interest, so we run:

```
Get-Service | Where-Object { $_.Status -eq 'Stopped' }
```

The output of this command can then be piped into a for each loop as you have suggested, and each service's properties or methods can be accessed using the `$_` shorthand:

```
Get-Service | Where-Object { $_.Status -eq 'Stopped' } | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Do something with $($_.ServiceName)"
}
```

It is possible to restart services in this manner, using `$_.Start()`, but I would recommend writing some error handling into the process if that's your ultimate aim.'

If you need more information, such as the executable, you might want to look here:

[How can I extract "Path to executable" of all services with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24449113/how-can-i-extract-path-to-executable-of-all-services-with-powershell)

Comment: Thank you! Not sure why I thought remote registry was something only accessible by sc. This works for me though, kudos!