# How to check a list of all services created by NSSM (non sucking service manager)?

Tags: service, windows-7, nssm

Okay, I have created some services in Windows 7 through NNSM (Non-Sucking Service Manager) but now I don't know their service names anymore and I want to edit/remove them.

How can I find a list of the services installed through NSSM?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Every service added through NSSM, points to nssm.exe in the "Path to executable". You can see this in the Services MMC snap-in by right-clicking a service and choosing "Properties".

Run the following in Powershell to get a list of all services with "nssm" in the PathName (Based off this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24449854/7470843)

```
Get-WmiObject win32_service | ?{$_.PathName -like '*nssm*'} | select Name, DisplayName, State, PathName
```

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 Version 10.0.19043 Build 19043 and PowerShell v7.2.7 and I can no long user Get-WmiObject, instead I have to use the Get-CimInstance command.

```Get-CimInstance win32_service | ?{$_.PathName -like '*nssm*'} | select Name, DisplayName, State, PathName```

Answer (score 17):

Recently had the very same question, turns out the creator built this functionality in over 3 years ago: https://git.nssm.cc/nssm/nssm/commit/1f0b03b38f7d76814d1c7c627f64462362100223

Looks like he was targeting this for the 2.25 release version, so it's missing in most of the documentation on the website and the built-in help.. but if you are running a more recent 2.24 pre-release, just `nssm list` gets it done.

Comment: This command is not available in the current stable versions of NSSM.

Comment: I used nssm list and it worked great! Thanks.

Comment: I'm using `nssm 2.24-103-gdee49fc` and `nssm list` does nothing despite having a service running.

Comment: Seems 2.25 was never publicly released... Someone compiled it tho here. DYOR: https://github.com/kirillkovalenko/nssm/issues/25#issuecomment-1071190707